# HTMLIonIconElement is not defined

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular9, ionic5, ionicons

I'm trying to reference an IonIcon Element from my Template with

`@ViewChild('downIcon') downIcon: HTMLIonIconElement;`

But I always get an ReferenceError that HTMLIonIconElement is not defined, immediate after reloading the page (On every page, also route doesn't matter).

I imported the IonicModule, do I have to import something else?

Got this if I use HTMLElement
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `HTMLElement` instead of `HTMLIonIconElement`.

```
@ViewChild('icons') icons: HTMLElement;

ngAfterViewInit(): void {
  console.log(this.icons);
}
```

Here you'll get the reference of the `ion-icon` element.

Reference: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-tmjcr3?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.ts

Note: The `ViewChild` will initiate after the `ngAfterViewInit` lifecycle hooks.

Comment: Yes HTMLElement works, but for some reason I dont get back an ElementRef, instead I get an IonIcon Object. This object does not have a nativeElement property but an el property. As workaround i could set type of downIcon to any and convert downIcon.el to HTMLIonIconElement. But I don't get why that is.